# Find PDF file with Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to find PDF files with jquery.
I did it with DOCX files with the code:

```
 $(el).find('a[href$=".docx"]')
```

how can I do it for PDF files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace the `.docx` to `.pdf`

```
$(el).find('a[href$=".pdf"]')
```